# Angular2 showing null in IE

Tags: angular

I have the following in an Angular2 component:

`<div ng-if="heading" [innerHTML]="heading"></div>`

Chrome & Safari work fine - but IE is showing `null` in the DIV. I have no idea why... heading is `undefined`, double-checked!

Comment: What polyfill are you currently using for IE? Usually you need at least core js.

Comment: replace it with *ngIf="heading"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct Syntax in Angular2 should be

```
<div *ngIf="heading" [innerHTML]="heading"></div>
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple..... thankyou.
Any idea why ng-if was working in Chrome?

Comment: I guess chrome still supports Angular 1 style & For IE you need to add extra polyfill...
u can accept this as answer if it helped :p

Comment: It wasn't working in Chrome or Safari. They just don't put in the "null" that IE does when heading is undefined. If you had looked in the elements panel, you would see that the content was still there when you had ng-if.

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't like the fact that you have to do ngIf whenever the innerHTML may be undefined, here's a solution to resolve this across your app:

```
constructor(sanitize: DomSanitizer) {
    // override the sanitize method so that it returns an empty string instead of null so that IE doesn't show "null" in the DOM
    sanitize.sanitize = function(context: SecurityContext, value: SafeValue | string | null) {
        return (sanitize as any).__proto__.sanitize.call((sanitize as any), context, value) || '';
    };
}
```

I place this in the app.module constructor.

You may ask, "why such a hacky approach?" That's largely because DomSanitizer is an interface acting as a class. The real sanitization happens in the DomSanitizerImpl class that isn't publicly exposed.

EDIT 6/18/19
Here's one for textContent as its done differently but produces undefined in IE

```
constructor(renderer: Renderer2) {
    /**
     * in IE, textContent = undefined gets put in the DOM as string, "undefined".
     * this is to override that behavior. We would put this in app.module
     * with the hack for DOM sanitization but in order to access the renderer,
     * we need to be in a component
     */
    const setProperty = (renderer as any).__proto__.setProperty;
    (renderer as any).__proto__.setProperty = function(el: Element, name: string, value: string) {
      if (name === 'textContent' && value === undefined) {
        value = '';
      }
      setProperty.call(this, el, name, value);
    };
  }
```

Comment: This is interesting, but why are the other browsers handling this differently here?

Comment: @jsgoupil IE seems to treat innerHTML and textContent values of "null" as a string value "null". It might do this because null is an object: http://www.ajaymatharu.com/javascript-difference-between-undefined-and-null/ Other browsers know that null is defined as the absence of content

Comment: Indeed, it must be that.
I just tried `$0.innerHTML = null;` in both browser and Edge behaves like writing the NULL value out.

Comment: This is the right approach, why would anyone want to ngIf accross the entire application wherever they've got innerHTML...

Answer (score 0):

It is **`*ngIf`**

```
<div *ngIf="heading" [innerHTML]="heading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 NgIf syntax:

```
<div *ngIf="condition">...</div>
<div template="ngIf condition">...</div>
<template [ngIf]="condition"><div>...</div></template>
```

Example:

```
<div *ngIf="errorCount > 0" class="error">
  <!-- Error message displayed when the errorCount property in the current context is greater than 0. -->
  {{errorCount}} errors detected
</div>
```