# IE/Edge renders "null" when model property is undefined

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular5, microsoft-edge

I'm using Angular 5 and when I have a template binding for some data in my model and the model property that I'm binding to is missing IE/Edge renders the string "null".

EX:

```
<span [innerHTML]="pagemodel.someproperty">
```

If `pagemodel.someproperty` doesn't exist then IE/Edge will render "null" in the span tag.  This occurs because my pagemodel comes from a service that will not send properties that are default values like empty strings, zeros, or true.  This is done to minimize the size of the data sent to the browser.  I could add `pagemodel.someproperty ? pagemodel.someproperty : ''` to all the bindings but don't really want to add all that extra code to my project.

Comment: You can find two suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42498842/1009922).

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use `[innerHTML]`? If you use interpolation, the behavior is correct in IE11: `<span>{{pagemodel.someproperty}}</span>`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vcwnq) for a demo.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for finding that, don't know why Google couldn't find that post when I searched (and searched and searched).

Answer (score 1):

There are some work around to fix this from my understanding,

1. you can use ***ngIf="pagemodel.someproperty"** to check data is ready in component to display in template.
2. You can set a dummy value like **pagemodel['someproperty']="";** in component by default and replace with actual value when available.
3. Or you can use a DOM Sanitizer class object and set nulls to " " 
   (But aware of security concepts of DOMSanitizer too)